# Display repository revision number in ASP.NET application after automated build

Tags: c#, asp.net, svn, jenkins, version-control

I have an ASP.NET web application and commit changes to a VisualSVN repository.

I use Jenkins to build the application from the repository to a number of different environments including Dev, UAT and Live.

The Dev environment is always built from the most recent repository revision, but the other environments are built by passing the revision number we want to build through to jenkins as a parameter.

As each of these environments will be built on different revisions of the repository, it would be useful to be able to display the revision number in the application.

Does anybody know how to do this, unfortunately I have no idea so haven't tried anything yet. All of the answers on Stack Overflow that I have found are from almost 9 years ago so I hoped someone could give me an up to date solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Install SVN CLI in the Jenkins master box 
and Use SVN command 
$revision_number as parameter to the job
run shell

```
$revision_number  #as parameter to the jo
svn export  -r $revision_number  http://SVNURL
```

This will checkout the particular revision in our Workspace

There is some plug called  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Release+Manager

This plugin allows you to set up a job in Jenkins for building specific revisions of a project.

Comment: I'm not sure if this has answered my question? My project is already able to build from a specific revision of the repository. I want to be able to display that revision number in the web application, like SO does in the footer of this page.

Comment: you have $revision_numeber  value  from jenkins parameter you can use enviornement inject plugin to write it to a properties file and then read it in your web application  from that particular file or  write a post build action to wirte the variable some where